# How to Split Firebug "Element" and "Console" into 2 windows?

Tags: firebug

I recently work a lot with Dom and Javascript, and repeated many times of switching from Elements and Consoles tab. Just wondering is there anyway that I can split 2 Tabs into different window panes?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows the Chrome DevTools, not Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do exactly what you're asking, but you could open the console from Firefox's built in developer tools and the HTML pane on Firebug. Then you could position them any way you like.

I prefer Firebug to the built in tools, but the built in tools have come a long way recently and the console is (for me) close enough for what I need.